# How to stub view model in ui5?

Tags: sapui5, sinon, qunit

I'm new to qunit + sinon.js, I want to write a unit test for function `onMultiSelectPress`, so I need to mock:

`this.myController._oList`

`this.myController.getResourceBundle()`

`this.myController.getModel("masterView")`

Right?

I'm stuck at get a stub for `getModel("masterView")`, any suggestion?

```
onInit : function () {
    var oList = this.byId("list"),
        oViewModel = this._createViewModel();   
    this._oList = oList;
    this.setModel(oViewModel, "masterView");    
},

_createViewModel : function() {
    return new JSONModel({
        isFilterBarVisible: false,
        filterBarLabel: "",
        delay: 0,
        title: this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterTitleCount", [0]),
        noDataText: this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataText"),
        sortBy: "Name",
        groupBy: "None",
        listMode: "SingleSelectMaster",
        showDeleteButton: false
    });
},

getModel : function (sName) {
    return this.getView().getModel(sName);
},

onMultiSelectPress : function () {
    var oMasterViewModel = this.getModel("masterView");

    switch(this._oList.getMode()) {
        case "MultiSelect":
            oMasterViewModel.setProperty("/listMode", "SingleSelectMaster");
            oMasterViewModel.setProperty("/showDeleteButton", false);
            break;
        case "SingleSelectMaster":
            oMasterViewModel.setProperty("/listMode", "MultiSelect");
            oMasterViewModel.setProperty("/showDeleteButton", true);
            break;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a oViewStub in `beforeEach`， and set an empty JSON model using for testing.

```
    QUnit.module("MasterController", {
        beforeEach: function() {
            this.oMasterController = new MasterController();
            this.models = {};
            var oViewStub = {
                setModel: function(model, name) {
                    this.models[name] = model;
                }.bind(this),
                getModel: function(name) {
                    return this.models[name];
                }.bind(this)
            };
            sinon.stub(Controller.prototype, "getView").returns(oViewStub);
        },

        afterEach: function() {
            this.oMasterController.destroy();
            jQuery.each(this.models, function(i, model) {
                model.destroy();
            });
            Controller.prototype.getView.restore();
        }
    });

    QUnit.test("test onMultiSelectPress() ", function(assert) {
        var oMasterController = this.oMasterController;
        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        oMasterController.setModel(oModel, "masterView");
        var oMasterViewModel = oMasterController.getModel("masterView");

        oMasterController._oList = new sap.m.List();
        sinon.stub(oMasterController._oList, "getMode").returns("MultiSelect");
        oMasterController.onMultiSelectPress();
        assert.strictEqual(oMasterViewModel.getProperty("/listMode"), "SingleSelectMaster", "Did change list mode to SingleSelectMaster");
        assert.strictEqual(oMasterViewModel.getProperty("/showDeleteButton"), false, "Did hide the delete button");

        oMasterController._oList.getMode.restore();
        sinon.stub(oMasterController._oList, "getMode").returns("SingleSelectMaster");
        oMasterController.onMultiSelectPress();
        assert.strictEqual(oMasterViewModel.getProperty("/listMode"), "MultiSelect", "Did change list mode to MultiSelect");
        assert.strictEqual(oMasterViewModel.getProperty("/showDeleteButton"), true, "Did show the delete button");

        oMasterController._oList.destroy();
    });
```

Comment: How I can unit test onInit method ? I can test method existence but not able to figure out to test JSON inside it. `onInit: function onInit() {
// HTML string bound to the formatted text control
var oModel = new JSONModel({
title:
'Hello',
message:
'<p>You </p>' +
accept: 'I Accept',
decline: 'I Decline'
});
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},
`

Comment: `assert.ok(this.getView().getModel(oModel))` ? @user557657

Comment: I am not able to get `this` reference in the unit test.

Comment: @user557657, my mistake. For `this.oMasterController = new MasterController();` , try log out `this.oMasterController.getView().getModel(oModel)`